# JQuery Datatables pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I can't get my pagination to work after I added a date filtering plug-in to datatables.
The original code was like this and it was picking up the pagination fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#table1').dataTable({
  'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
 });
```

this is my current one with the plug in variables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable();
 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
 /* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
 $('#min').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );
 $('#max').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend asking on the [Datatables](http://datatables.net/forums/) forums. I asked a few questions on there when I was doing some work with the plugin and they were answered quickly. The plugin developer uses the forums too, so somebody there will be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your current function, this part:

```
var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable();
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
```

should be written like this:

```
var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
});
```

---

**Edit**

In case it wasn't clear, the full jQuery code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
        'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
    });
    /* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
    $('#min').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );
    $('#max').keyup( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );
});
```

Comment: i've updated it now im getting this error.DataTables warning (table id = 'table1'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, please pass either no arguments to the dataTable() function, or set bRetrieve to true. Alternatively, to destory the old table and create a new one, set bDestroy to true (note that a lot of changes to the configuration can be made through the API which is usually much faster).

Comment: @glenn: I'm not sure, but it sounds like you are creating duplicate dataTables. Can you edit your question to include your current jQuery code and the relevant HTML? I've edited my answer to include the full example in case it wasn't clear enough.